# Java - Generic interface for visitors

Tags: java, interface, java-8, visitor-pattern, dynamic-dispatch

I use the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to execute functions on a hierarchy of classes. For example:

```
// Node.java

public abstract class Node {}

// Addition.java

public final class Addition extends Node {
    public final Node e1;
    public final Node e2;

    public Addition(final Node e1, final Node e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }
}

// Multiplication.java

public final class Multiplication extends Node {
    public final Node e1;
    public final Node e2;

    public Multiplication(final Node e1, final Node e2) {
        this.e1 = e1;
        this.e2 = e2;
    }
}

// Constant.java

public final class Constant extends Node {
    public final int value;

    public Constant(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Since I have different functions taking a node and returning different types, I define an interface for my visitors:

```
public interface INodeVisitor<T> {
    public abstract T visit(final Addition add);
    public abstract T visit(final Multiplication add);
    public abstract T visit(final Constant add);

    public default T visit(final Node node) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown node: " + node.getClass() + ".");
    }
}
```

Then I can define a generic method `accept()` for all my nodes which allows me to define new visitors with no need to modify the nodes:

```
// I add this in the definition of every node.
public <T> T accept(final INodeVisitor<T> visitor) {
    return visitor.visit(this);
}
```

I can now define functions on nodes, for example:

```
// This visitor is a function on Nodes and returns an Integer.
public final class NodeEvaluationVisitor implements INodeVisitor<Integer> {
    public final Integer visit(final Addition add) {
        return add.e1.accept(this) + add.e2.accept(this);
    }

    public final Integer visit(final Multiplication mul) {
        return mul.e1.accept(this) * mul.e2.accept(this);
    }

    public final Integer visit(final Constant c) {
        return c.value;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly:

```
public class Main {
    public static Integer eval(final Node n) {
        return n.accept(new NodeEvaluationVisitor());
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Node n = new Addition(new Multiplication(new Constant(5), new Constant(8)), new Constant(2));
        System.out.println(eval(n));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

This works because my interface has access to all the hierarchy. My problem arises when `Node` is defined in `projectA`, and its subclasses are defined in `projectB` which depends on `projectA`.

Since `Node` also needs to define an `accept()` method that takes an `INodeVisitor` as argument, I define my interface in `projectA`. I can then define my concrete visitors in `projectB`.

However, this means that my interface needs to be generic about the subclasses of `Node`, which does not seem to be possible. With this interface:

```
public interface INodeVisitor<T> {
    public default T visit(final Node node) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown node: " + node.getClass() + ".");
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown node: class Addition.
at INodeVisitor.visit(INodeVisitor.java:5)
at Addition.accept(Addition.java:14)
at Main.eval(Main.java:9)
at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Since Java's dynamic dispatch chooses the `default` method. Same result with:

```
public interface INodeVisitor<T> {
    public default <U extends Node> T visit(final U node) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown node: " + node.getClass() + ".");
    }
}
```

The only way I found to make this work is to do the dispatch manually:

```
public interface INodeVisitor<T> {
    public abstract T visit(final Node node);
}
```

And so in `NodeEvaluationVisitor`:

```
@Override
public final Integer visit(final Node node) {
    if (node instanceof Addition)
        return visit((Addition) node);
    if (node instanceof Multiplication)
        return visit((Multiplication) node);
    if (node instanceof Constant)
        return visit((Constant) node);
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown node: " + node.getClass() + ".");
}
```

**Question:** Is there a better solution in Java than the unsatisfactory manual dispatch solution above? Thank you for reading and for your suggestions.

**Edit:** The solution I implemented in the end (still unsatisfactory) is to add a specific interface, say `INodeSpecificVisitor<T>`, in `projectB`, have the visitors implement this specific interface, and do the manual dispatch in `INodeSpecificVisitor`. That way at least the manual dispatch is factorized between the visitors.

Comment: Just a little remark, no need to declare your methods `final` if your class is already `final` because they are automatically `final`.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes it's an habit I took to put `final` everywhere. :-) Thank you for the remark.

Comment: That’s the fundamental limitation of the Visitor Pattern, that its interface fixes a particular set of subclasses. It won’t work with having the subclasses in a different project than the base type. But what is the benefit of this separation? The technical problems you have, are a direct result of the conceptual deficiency. You want to provide a subclass-specific feature on a base class that you want to be independent of the subclasses…

Comment: You can, however, reduce the ugliness of the repeated `instanceof` checks, but letting all supported node classes implement a ProjectB specific interface, defining the required `accept` method. So you need only one `instanceof` check.

Comment: Only regarding `projectA`, what is the use-case for a generic `Node` class that can be visited by someone who should take care of the children defined somewhere? I smell too many unnecessary levels of abstraction - either dispatch manually or add an abstract method to `Node` for the use-cases where `Node` has to be treated without the knowledge of *any* subclass.

Comment: @Holger @Smutje I am working on an existing project that has this separation between the "`Node`" class and its subclasses. The developers did not have a need to visit this class and I do, which is why I stumbled across this problem. I like Holger's idea, I will try that. Thank you both for your comments.